# how to hide soft keyboard in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to hide keyboard in fragments in android.Because once it displays it remain visible in all fragments.I try this method

```
    public static void hideKeyboard(Context ctx) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // check if no view has focus:
    View v = ((Activity) ctx).getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null)
        return;

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

and call this method on button click

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboard(ctx);
                login();


        }
    });
```

but this give error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: why do you trying to find some view? pass View v as a parameter to your hideKeyboard method, v.getContext() will give you the right context and that would be method with 2 lines of code

Comment: Have you initialized or assigned `ctx` with a Context object?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Please elaborate your answer with code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **For Java**

**try this one**

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null) {
            return;
        }
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

**to call this just pass below code from your onclick of button**

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
                login();


        }
    });
```

> **For Kotlin**

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard(activity:Activity) {
  if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null){
    return
  }
  val inputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0)
}
```

**pass below code from your onclick of button**

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener() {
  fun onClick(v:View) {
    hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity())
    login()
  }
})
```

Comment: This doesn´t work with fragments, on a mate 20 pro device

Answer (score 3):

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       hideKeyboard(v);
       login();
   }
});
```

And the hide keyboard method in some Utility class

```
public static void hideKeyboard(@NonNull View v) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for kotlin users
create a file and add this code

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    if (activity.currentFocus == null) {
        return
    }
    val inputMethodManager =
        activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Now call this method anywhere using

```
hideSoftKeyboard(requireActivity())
```

Happy coding..NB for kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Hide it using the window token from your fragment view

**For Kotlin -**

```
if (activity != null){
    // Hide soft keyboard
    val imm =
        activity!!.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(requireView().windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```